# How to filter out data into unique pandas dataframes from a combined csv of multiple datatypes?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

Sample csv

```
time,type,-1,
time,type,0,w
time,type,1,a,12,b,13,c,15,name,apple
time,type,5,r,2,s,43,t,45,u,67,style,blue,font,13
time,type,11,a,12,c,15
time,type,5,r,2,s,43,t,45,u,67,style,green,font,15
time,type,1,a,12,b,13,c,15,name,apple
time,type,11,a,12,c,15
time,type,5,r,2,s,43,t,45,u,67,style,green,font,15
time,type,1,a,12,b,13,c,15,name,apple
time,type,5,r,2,s,43,t,45,u,67,style,yellow,font,9
time,type,19,b,12
type,19,b,42
```

I would like to filter each of the following "type,1", "type,5", "type,11", "type,19" into a separate pandas frame for further analysis. What's the best way to do it ? [Also, I will be ignoring "type,0" and "type,-1"]

Sample Code

```
import pandas as pd

type1_header = ['type','a','b','c','name']
type5_header = ['type','r','s','t','u','style','font']
type11_header = ['type','a','c']
type19_header = ['type','b']

type1_data = pd.read_csv(file_path_to_csv, usecols=[2,4,6,8,10] , names=type1_header)
type5_data = pd.read_csv(file_path_to_csv, usecols=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14] , names=type5_header)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

headers = {1:['a','b','c','name'],
           5:['r','s','t','u','style','font'],
}

usecols = {1:[4,6,8,10],
           5:[4,6,8,10,12,14],
           }


frames = {}
for h in headers:
    frames[h] = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers[h])

count = 0
for line in open('irreg.csv'):
    row = line.split(',')
    count += 1
    ID = int(row[2])
    row_subset = []
    if ID in frames:
        for col in usecols[ID]: row_subset.append(row[col])
        frames[ID].loc[len(frames[ID])] = row_subset
    else:
        print('WARNING: line %d: type %s not found'%(count, row[2]))
```

Although, that done, how often do you do this and how often does the data change? For a one-off it's probably easiest to split up the incoming csv file, e.g. by

```
 grep type,19 irreg.csv > 19.csv
```

at the commandline, and then import each csv according to its headers and usecols.